# Interpolate physics sim point cache?

Tags: physics, baking, cloth-simulation, soft-body

The deforming physics sims all create huge amounts of data.

In a lot of cases, storing an entire shape for every frame is arguably wasteful.

Is there any way to simulate only every couple frames, and then interpolate the mesh data across them during playback?

Time remapping seems to extend the playback length of a physics simulation, but with popping instead of interpolation.

Comment: You could try multiple cases of “apply as shape key.” I’m not sure how to implement that though. It sounds like the tool for the job since relative shape keys can be played back in an order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundled [`.PC2`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/pc2.html) and [`.MDD`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/shape_mdd.html) add-ons can be used to export the simulation data into an external file at a lower frame rate/step.

The [Mesh Cache](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/mesh_cache.html) modifier can then be used to load that external file back onto the base mesh and play it back at a different speed with interpolation between all exported frames.